# Java how to check if mysql is running

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

I just find this code and I use to check if MYSQL Server is running after every ten second...by call this method

```
public static boolean hostAvailabilityCheck(String address, int port) {
try (Socket s = new Socket(address, port)) {
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        /* ignore */
    }
    return false;
}
```

so do I do it right, or there is other better way for check for MYSQL if still running after some second? please help me.

Comment: please check this there is a way given to check mysql is running [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472805/how-can-i-check-if-mysql-and-tomcat-are-running)

Comment: Using a socket will only verify that something is running on the specified port, this might not be MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port can be open without any application listening to it. If you want to see also that your mySQL application is listening on the port, get mySQL connector for JAVA and look how to establish a connection - with user name and password.

Comment: so that means if the port is open MYSQL is running?

Comment: No :) create a connection to a mysql using mysql driver for java. Just google it, it is first thing to pop up. There is also documentation to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this i think it is a better approach to use Hibernate or other ORM capabilities for create Datasources and Connection Pools, because without it you will have to deal with resource management yourself.

Check this [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html),for an example of how to create and use a Session and the associated connection.

Hibernates uses c3p0 to handle datasource creation and connections, you can configure using properties all the parameters, and this will handle reconnections for you keeping a conection pool ready for use. Also it can validate the connection with a validation query

Comment: Just to say, using ORM for creating a session against mysql seems like overkill to me :) you still need the driver for mysql (which is probably included in orm you mentioned)

Comment: @PeterMajko indeed but i post this as answer also referring to c3p0, of you can do the things by hand but we don't know the exact behaviour of the application if the application is database intensive with CRUD behaviour using the orm its a suitable option, because it allows him to develop faster wihtout handling connection by himself. He can always use plain JDBC with mysql driver